# Forbid the owner of a user from GRANTing on that table

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to allow a database user to be able to alter/drop (certain) tables, but *not* GRANT privileges on them. Is this possible?

It looks like they need to be the owner of the tables, but from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html

> The right to drop an object, or to alter its definition in any way, is not treated as a grantable privilege; it is inherent in the owner, and cannot be granted or revoked. (However, a similar effect can be obtained by granting or revoking membership in the role that owns the object; see below.) The owner implicitly has all grant options for the object, too.

This sounds like it's not possible. However, is this definitely the case? Is there some way with triggers for example to make certain GRANTs fail?

Comment: You cannot stop the owner from issuing grants but I assume the user would work through an procedure/function you've created. You put that is a separate schema then can grant users execute on the procedure/function.  Once the object is created it's owned, or made to be owned by that role , then grant the user that created it the DML access. That way the user cannot issue grants because they are not actually the owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, only the owner of a table or a superuser can `ALTER` or `DROP` it, and these users can always `GRANT` privileges on the table.

Your only option is to create an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html) that fires on `GRANT` and throws an error for the tables where it should be forbidden.